# Testing a get action with view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nunit, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I have the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var news = newsRepository.GetNewsByID(id);

   Mapper.CreateMap<News, NewsEditModel>();
   var newsEditModel =
      (NewsEditModel)Mapper.Map(news, typeof(News), typeof(NewsEditModel));

   return View(newsEditModel);
}
```

And the corresponding test:

```
[Test]
public void Edit_should_render_view()
{
   // Arrange
   var id = 1;
   var newsEditModel = new NewsEditModel();

   // Act
   var actual = sut.Edit(id);

   // Assert
   actual
      .AssertViewRendered()
      .WithViewData<NewsEditModel>()
      .ShouldBe(newsEditModel);
}
```

In the NUnit GUI I get the following error:

MyProject.Web.UnitTests.Controllers.NewsControllerTests.Edit_should_render_view:
MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException : was MyProject.Web.Common.ViewData.NewsEditModel but expected MyProject.Web.Common.ViewData.NewsEditModel

I don't know how to write the corresponding unit test.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is comparing two different instances of `NewsEditModel` - one instance that you create in your test code, and the other that is created in the action method.

If you want to examine the model property values as part of your test, you could do this:

```
var model = actual
  .AssertViewRendered()
  .WithViewData<NewsEditModel>();

// Check that model is not null
Assert.That(model, Is.Not.Null);  

// Check that model ID is same as passed into action method
Assert.That(model.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
// or alternatively ...
model.Id.ShouldBe(1);
```

Comment: Yes someone told me this already, but how would I change it to make the test past sucessfully?  I am going to need to populate the NewsEditModel properties with a News object that I get from a database.

Comment: Hopefully my example will help to clarify how to examine the property values. If you are fetching values from a database, you should consider whether you can mock the database retrieval code so that you are only unit testing your controller action, not the database layer as well.

Comment: @RichTea: I'm not trying to validate model properties.  What I was trying to say is that in my controller I will have an NewsEditModel. This models properties will be populated/mapped from a News object that I got from a database call.  And then I will have return View(newsEditModel);.

Comment: If you're not validating the model properties then you can just omit the last line in my example. Then your unit test will simply be verifying that a view is rendered, and that the view data for that view is the correct type (NewsEditModel).

Comment: Ok cool. I just updated my Edit. Please take a peak at what I am trying to accomplish. Is your answer still the same? When would I use ShouldBe?

Comment: If you don't want to examine the properties of the model then you don't need to use ShouldBe. But if I were writing your unit test, I would at least assert that model is not null, and that model.Id.ShouldBe(1) (assuming there is an Id property on NewsEditModel). ShouldBe will compare two objects for equality, which is no use for comparing two NewsEditModel instances, unless of course they are the same instance, like when you use mocking to replace the database layer - but that's another question :)

Comment: @RichTea: Update your answer with the checks you mentioned here please :)

Comment: @RichTEa: Hang in there, I have not had time to look at your answer yet, been busy yesterday!